# Problem by testing my exceptions. Why does the isinstance() not work? Why is it ApiException() instead of ApiException?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

[Solved, look at my answer below]

I have a problem with my unit tests. I have a test for testing, if the code, which handles the APIs, throws an exception, if the HTTP status code isn't good. Context: The code is for an automated merge process between jira and gitlab.

My Exception Class:

```py
import inspect


class ApiException(Exception):
  def __init__(self, response) -> None:
    self.http_code = response.status_code
    self.message = response.text.replace("\n", " ")
    self.caller = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe(), 2)[1]
    self.caller_file = self.caller[1]
    self.caller_line = self.caller[2]

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"Error code {self.http_code} with message '{self.message}' in file {self.caller_file} line {self.caller_line}"
```

The part where the GitLab API is used, where the exception will be thrown:

```py
if response.ok:
  return MergeRequest(json.loads(response.text))
else:
  raise ApiException(response=response)
```

The Unittest:

```py
class TestException(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_raise_exception(self):
    api_call = ApiCall()
    api_response = ApiCallResponse()
    api_response.ok = False
    api_response.status_code = 401
    api_call.get_with_header = MagicMock(return_value=api_response)

    gitlab = GitLab(logger=TestLogger, api_call=api_call)

    try:
      gitlab.get_project_by_url("https://git.mycompany.de/group/project")
      assert False
    except Exception as err:
      TestLogger.info(type(err))
      TestLogger.info(isinstance(err, ApiException))
      assert isinstance(err, ApiException)
```

It always fails with:

```bash
Merge_Service_Test |         try:
Merge_Service_Test |             gitlab.get_project_by_url("https://git.mycompany.de/group/project")
Merge_Service_Test |             assert False
Merge_Service_Test |         except Exception as err:
Merge_Service_Test |             TestLogger.info(err)
Merge_Service_Test | >           assert isinstance(err, ApiException)
Merge_Service_Test | E           assert False
Merge_Service_Test | E            +  where False = isinstance(ApiException(), ApiException)
```

I want to test, if it's the right exception, but `isinstance()` says, that they are two different types. When I do `logger.info(type(err))`, it returns `<class 'APIs.api_exceptions.ApiException'>`, which is the right exception type.

Has anyone here an idea, what my problem is and how I could solve it?

Comment: Just to be sure, `class ApiException(Exception):` is defined in file `api_exceptions` in `APIs` module?

Comment: Also remove ChatGPT code, that's just noise.

Comment: Yes thats in `api_exceptions`

Comment: Is the exception caught if you except `ApiException` instead of generic `Exception`?

Comment: I did now 
`except ApiException: assert True`
and the exception is not caught in the except block. I don't understand this because I raised the ApiException...

Comment: It feels like `ApiException` in the test namespace is not the same `ApiException` that is raised due to error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], for example in the code you show where does `ApiException` come from? Have you declared it somewhere in the same file? Is it imported in the file? Again the same thing for the code which raises the actual exception. Also is there any wildcard imports, etc. in your files? Remember we should be able to reproduce your issue by copy pasting the code and running it.

Comment: Why does the test failure message mention a function call to `merge_process.start()`, when that code is not actually in the unit test?  I think you've shown us the wrong code.

Comment: There are two tests with the same error and the same structure. Sorry for that, I've mixed those here :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried a simple repro with this code :

```py
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args: object) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args)


def test_my_error():
    try:
        raise MyError("test error")
    except Exception as err:
        assert isinstance(err, MyError)
        assert err.__class__ is MyError
```

This passes without problem. Something might be wrong with ApiException.
Even though both asserts pass, the first one is recommended. My way of doing this though is to take care of the type-checking in the except condition like so :

```py
def test_my_error():
    try:
        raise MyError("test error")
        assert False
    except MyError:
        assert True
    except Exception:
        assert False
```

This might work in your case

Comment: "Something might be wrong with ApiException" is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. The problem was, that I imported the module the wrong way.

```
├── src
│   ├── APIs
│   │   ├── api_call.py
│   │   ├── api_exceptions.py <-- Here is the ApiException
│   │   ├── gitlab.py <-- Here is the tested API module
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── jira.py
|   ├── __init__.py
|   |...
|
└── tests
    ├── integration
    │   ├── __init__.py
    |   |── test_dry_run.py
    |   ├── test_exception.py <--- Here is the test, which failed
    |   ├── test_jira_issues.py
    |   └── test_regex.py
    |...
```

The import in the Test was wrong. I've imported from `src.APIs.api_exceptions.ApiException` instead of `APIs.api_exceptions.ApiException`. How ever, it works. Python imports are strange :(

Also sorry for not writing the structure to my question. Big thanks to those, who tried to help me and telling me, how I should write my questions here.